# There is no nn$result.matrix in neuralnet in r

Tags: r, neural-network

I did neuralnet in R

```
test_wocoal=sample(dim(df_wocoal)[1],8570)
sx=scale(df_wocoal);sx=as.data.frame(sx)
train=sx[-test_wocoal,];test=sx[test_wocoal]

n=names(train)
form=as.formula(paste('Primary_Air_Flow~',paste(n[!n %in% 'primary_Air_Flow'],collapse='+')))

nn=neuralnet(form,data=train,hidden=3,linear.output,err.fct="ce",stepmax=1e+08,threshold=0.01)
```

the ftn 'neuralnet' was ended sucessfully.
So, i was doing 'compute'
But, the R gave me a warnings.

```
pre=compute(nn,test[,-1])
Error in nrow[w]*ncol[w] :non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In un.na(weights): in.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

So, i checked my data frame, but there is no NA(all cases are complete) and all columns are numeric.
I don't know why that error is comming
and, i checked component(?) in 'nn'
there is no 'result.matrix'.

'nn' has only 'numHiddenNodes','data','hidden','linear.output','err.fct','stepmax','threshold'

What problem is in here? How to solve it?